# Tensorflow Serving, online predictions: How to build a signature_def that accepts 'image_bytes' as input tensor name?

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I have successfully trained a Keras model and used it for predictions on my local machine, now i want to deploy it using Tensorflow Serving. My model takes images as input and returns a mask prediction.

According to the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/online-predict) my instances need to be formatted like this:

```py
{'image_bytes': {'b64': base64.b64encode(jpeg_data).decode()}}
```

Now, the `saved_model.pb` file automatically saved by my Keras model has the following tensor names:

```py
input_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_image:0')
output_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('conv2d_23/Sigmoid:0')
```

therefore i need to save a new `saved_model.pb` file with a different `signature_def`.

I tried the following (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_saved_model.py) for reference), which works:

```py
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ['serve'], 'path/to/saved/model/')
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_image:0')
    output_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('conv2d_23/Sigmoid:0')
    tensor_info_input = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(input_tensor) 
    tensor_info_output = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(output_tensor)
    prediction_signature = (
        tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
            inputs={'image_bytes': tensor_info_input},
            outputs={'output_bytes': tensor_info_output},
method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder('path/to/saved/new_model/')
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
        sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        signature_def_map={'predict_images': prediction_signature, })
    builder.save()
```

but when i deploy the model and request predictions to the AI platform, i get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Prediction failed: Error processing input: Expected float32, got {'b64': 'Prm4OD7JyEg+paQkPrGwMD7BwEA'} of type 'dict' instead.
```

readapting the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216067/tensorflow-serving-prediction-as-b64-output-top-result/48245749#48245749), i also tried to rewrite

```py
input_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_image:0')
```

as

```py
image_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='b64')
graph_input_def = graph.as_graph_def()
input_tensor, = tf.import_graph_def(
    graph_input_def,
    input_map={'b64:0': image_placeholder},
    return_elements=['input_image:0'])
```

with the (wrong) understanding that this would add a layer on top of my input tensor with matching `'b64'` name (as per documentation) that accepts a string and connects it the original input tensor
but the error from the AI platform is the same.

(the relevant code i use for requesting a prediction is:

```py
instances = [{'image_bytes': {'b64': base64.b64encode(image).decode()}}]
response = service.projects().predict(
    name=name,
    body={'instances': instances}
).execute()
```

where `image` is a `numpy.ndarray` of `dtype('float32')`)

I feel i'm close enough but i'm definitely missing something. Can you please help?

Comment: I'm stuck with the same, Can you give me an example of the placeholder did you use ?

Answer (score 0):

After b64 encoded -> decoded, the buffer of img will be changed to type string and not fit your model input type.
You may try to add some [preprocess](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/r1.11/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.py#L172) in your model and send b64 request again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made some progress but still struggling, i created a new question for my current specific problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56275522/tensorflow-serving-how-to-decode-base64-encoded-png-images-during-preprocessing